# Dart and package root

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Im running some code using the dart VM from the command line.
the command is:

```
dart --checked -package-root=/dart/packages test_service.dart
```

however Im getting an error:

```
gf_service.dart': error: line 7 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:start/start.dart'  as start;
```

Im confused since in the dir referenced by "-package-root" argument Im definitely seeing the "start/start.dart" file, so it exists. the -package-root folder is also correct.

is there something Im missing?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need the `-package-root` argument but the directory that contains the script file should have a symbolic link to the packages directory of your package. `pub get` should create these symlinks.

Comment: unfortunately I already did that, and its not sufficient... a bit confusing.

Comment: Your script is within the `bin` directory of your package? Which OS are you using? On Linux I had this several times when the script was in a sub-subdirectory of `bin`. I just created the symlink `packages` pointing to `youpackage/packages` manually.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this issue is to use "--package-root" as the argument name, and not "-package-root" as googles own dart documentation says
https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart-vm.html

(this should be fixed)

Im using dart vm 1.3.0